# AdMob disable virus ad banners

Tags: android, admob

I am using AdMob in my app. Now I would like to know if I can disable virus ads. User are complaining about this and deinstall my app. How can I achieve this? I looked into settings in AdMob, but it is just possible to disable categories and I do not know which category I should choose.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: I am pretty sure you can do nothing about it (SPAM, viruses and spyware are out there...), apart from reporting the infected banners directly to AdMob and expecting that they will remove them. Don't expect virus ads to be categorised, that would be illegal.

Comment: I think this is really a serious issue. You will lose your users and also get a bad reputation... thanks

Answer (score 1):

I blocked these URLs:

```
p.momoxxio.com
wrwoo.com
211get.com
```

and my clients don't see the virus ads any more.

Please note:

- It takes a while to take effect
- You might be seeing virus ads from some other provider
- Don't forget to report the ads if they appear

If that doesn't help, enable "Ad review center" in admob console, and wait for the ad to appear there, then block it.

Answer (score 0):

Well it is possible to block the categories of add in admob. just follow these steps.

1)Log into admob

2)Go to monetize ->Select your app from left side

3)Then go to allow and block ads.

4)Select your category to filter ads.(here you may have to research on the category of add you want to block)

done !

Comment: yes I know this to block a category. It is about how to disable/block "your device is infected" ads.

Comment: are they interstellar ads ?

Comment: are you sure it is coming from admob ?sorry to ask you so many questions